# How to properly switch between gcc versions?

Tags: c++, gcc

I want to play with C++ 2011, so I need the unreleased gcc 4.7. I was able to succesfully get the svn trunk and compile it.

I want to keep the default gcc of my system for safety, so I configured gcc4.7 with a *--prefix* and installed it in a non-standard location.

Now how should I enable gcc 4.7 over the default gcc of my system ?

I already changed the *CC* and *CXX* variables, I updated my *PATH* to point on the gcc 4.7 *bin* dir first. When I type *gcc --version* I get 4.7 OK.

But gcc is more than just an executable. There are many executables in gcc install dir. There are also default includes and std lib c++.

So far, every blog entry / SO question I found on this subject speaks only about the *gcc* and *g++* executables.

Can anyone give me a list of the changes I need to do to the environment to fully use gcc 4.7 ?
update LD_LIBRARY_PATH ? How to give precedence to gcc 4.7 system includes ? Are there other things to consider ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Answered in the GCC FAQ: http://gcc.gnu.org/faq.html#multiple

Comment: I experienced strange segfaults after compiling with gcc 4.7. That's why I'm asking for informations I may have missed. Hence the "properly" in my question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer is: nothing; it just works. :)

GCC finds what it needs first relative to itself, second in the "prefix" it was configured with, and finally in the standard places. By this means it's perfectly safe to relocate it wherever you like, as long as you relocate *all* of it - but beware that the fall back behaviour can hide brokenness if the install is incomplete.

Comment: OK so most likely the problem I'm experiencing are coming from something else. Will try again.

Answer (score 2):

I would think that THE g++ is pretty much tangled up with things using C++ as the C library is tangled up with the system! Any layout changes in the C++ library classes will cause incompatibilities with other C++ programs or libraries. Thus, I wouldn't replace the system's C++ compiler or, more importantly, its standard C++ library at all (unless, maybe, the compiler vendor makes a strong claim that they retained binary compatibility with the version you are replacing).

To play or even use a different version of g++, using the prefix approach works fine. All the compiler specific tools are implicitly called from within g++ using an appropriate version and tools like ar, ld, ranblib, etc. are not really depending on the compiler version anyway. The important components uses internally are the standard library (both the headers and the library) and the preprocessor. When calling a version of g++ it figures out which of these it really needs.

BTW, when you want to play with C++2011 you can also have a look at clang.

Comment: Thanks, I tried clang, but it failed at spotting an error in my code that was causing crashes. gcc spotted it right away with a compile error outlining the problem. I stick to gcc since. Switching between clang and gcc is easier than switching between two gcc.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [GCC Configuration docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html). I am using program suffixes to distinguish between the different GCC versions. To do that add, e.g., `--progam-suffix=-4.7` to your `./configure` invocation.